# gradlew run in terminal gives Run Task not Found

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am currently experimenting with a mobile java Project, it's a google ar core , you can check it's Git Repository here   :
[GoogleArcore](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/augmented_faces_java)

I managed to run the app successfully while using android studio.

I cloned this project and opened it with ***vscode***,
and run

`./gradlew clean build`

this goes as expected!!

***Problem:***  : running `./gradelw run`  gives bellow error :

***run task is not found in the root project***

any approach to solving this !!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the plugin needed to have `run`  task available !

```
// root build.gradle
plugins {
    id('application')
}
```

- Now re-running `./gradlew build` does add the **run** task, provided by the plugin above .

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code to your `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' 
}
```

The `com.android.application` plugin already includes the task `run`, so your error should be fixed.

For more information regarding this plugin, read the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build#module-level) (Android), and [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html).

Comment: if you checked the repository you will find what you suggested in the 'build.gradle' under app folder!!! apply plugin: 'com.android.application' like soo.

Comment: What i understood from what your referring to is i have to cd to app folder and the run `./gradlew run` , but i use `./gradlew` for commands,located outside the app folder!!

Comment: Have you tried to add it to the root `build.gradle` file?

Comment: i haven't, yet:! i thought about this, but what's the point from having two similar plugins? haven't found any post state this. Overall i'll try that and get back!!

Comment: Usually, the `build.gradle` file is placed in the root, so that should be the cause for your problem since it says that the `run` task could not be found. If you found my answer helpful, please consider marking it as 'Accepted', thank you! :)